# Redux-form initial values from mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I take `notesFromStore` that are provided by `redux` into my `NoteEdit` component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { notesFromStore: state.notes };
}
```

And make them initial values of  `<Field name="title">` and `<Field name="content">` when component mounts?

```
class NoteEdit extends Component {

  onSumbit(values) {
    this.props.createNote(values, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }

  renderField(field) {
    const className = `form-group ${field.meta.touched && field.meta.error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label>{field.labelToShow}</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSumbit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          name="title"
          labelToShow="Note title"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          name="content"
          labelToShow="Note content"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate: validate,
  form: 'NoteNewFormUnique',
})(connect(null, { createNote })(NoteEdit));
```

The screen shows the data structure delivered from `redux mapStateToProps`

**EDIT:**

Thanks to: **@Ashish Choudhary** it worked! I will leave here my code for someone from future with a similar issue. Maybe it will help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class NoteEdit extends Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { change } = this.props
    const values = nextProps.initialValues;
    if (values !== null) {
      change('title', values.title);
      change('content', values.content);
    }
  }

  onSumbit(values) {
    this.props.prepareToEdit(values, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }

  renderField(field) {
    const className = `form-group ${field.meta.touched && field.meta.error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label>{field.labelToShow}</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSumbit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          name="title"
          labelToShow="Note title"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          name="content"
          labelToShow="Note content"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { initialValues: state.edit };
}


function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.title || values.title.length < 2) {
    errors.title = 'Enter note title that is at least 2 characters long!';
  }
  if (!values.content || values.content.length < 3) {
    errors.content = 'Enter note content that is at least 3 characters long!';
  }
  // If errors is empty, the form is fine to submit
  // If errors has any properties, it is invalid
  return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate: validate,
  form: 'NoteNewFormUnique',
})(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(NoteEdit));
```

Comment: Your screenshot shows lots of `notes`. Are you wanting to show all of them (as a `FieldArray`) or just one? How are you selecting which one?

Comment: I was in middle of it. More important for me was at that point to know how to show anything in that filed from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely, `change` function is the best way to bind the data in `redux-form` because it can be easily used anywhere inside the class... And hence there is not need to set initial state for the form...

```
class NoteEdit extends Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { change } = this.props
    const values = nextProps.initialValues.5931aa20b94dc80011c729d6
    change('title', values.title)
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSumbit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          name="title"
          labelToShow="Note title"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: where "mapStateToProps" is used then here? it should be passed to connect according to documentation, but it does not work in my case...

Comment: @AnarchistGeek `mapStateToProps` should be passed as first argument of  `connect`. This will give on the last line: `(connect(mapStateToProps, { createNote })(NoteEdit));`

Comment: @AnarchistGeek I hadn't concentrated on that... My aim is to set initial values to the form fields...

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic approach, I suggest using the following `componentWillReceiveProps` function. You do not need to specify which field to change as they are all read from `nextProps.initialValues`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { change, initialValues } = this.props
    const values = nextProps.initialValues;

    if(initialValues !== values){
        for (var key in values) {
            if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                change(key,values[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```